# Python Class Attribute Reference

Tags: python, class, object, attributes

File 1:

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
    def add_friend(friends):
        pass
def load_people():
    op = open("file.txt", "r")
    read = op.readlines()
    for i in read:
        p = Person(first_name, last_name)
        name = first_name + last_name
        p.add_friend(name)
    pass
```

File 2:

```
class Patient:

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, health):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.health = health


def load_patient():
    op = open("file.txt", "r")
    read = op.readlines()
    for i in read:
        pa = Patient(first_name, last_name, health)
    pass
```

I've 2 separate ".py files"
File 1 have a class called Person and a function called load_people, I've created an object called "p" in load_patient(my program is supposed to create an object for each line in the file, i.e for each name)
Then that object "p" is used to call a method called add_friend of "class Person" and this method will add a person into a list whenever it is called.

There are no issues with File1, my main concern is File2

In File2, the class we have now is called Patient and a function called load_patient 
Now, I'm supposed to the same thing I did for load_people function. So I created a new object in load_patient function for Patient class which should be used to call add_friend function to add the person into the list. But I'm getting AttributeError.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the question description is very wage.
"load_patient function for Patient class which should be used to call add_friend function" - Patient has to inherit from Person class to do so and it's not doing.

Code is not pasted propery.
Do you mean name = Person.first_name + Person.last_name ?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused, please don't mind the syntax, my question is, how can use the object that I've created in the load_patient function to call add_friend function and pass a variable into it. Something like, pa.add_friend(name). Whenever the function is called a name from file will be passed into it. But whenever I do this, I'm getting an attribute error that says Patient object doesn't have attribute. I've tried using the object of the Person class("p") but then it says invalid reference. Is there any way I can do this. Please suggest me a solution

Comment: Please pass the complete code that you tried and not working